How to get Get BUTT to override Liquid Soap playlist
I have Liquid Soap set up and it's playing an M3U playlist from my Icecast server fine.
I want to connect live via BUTT and have it override Liquid Soap.
I have Icecast sources set to 2 but this doesn't allow BUTT to take over. BUTT won't connect when Liquid Soap is running. When I kill it, BUTT is able to connect fine.
BUTT connects toe the Icecast server via its IP address (eg. xx.xx.xx.xx)
Liquid soap is on the Icecast server so the config file is using localhost.
Here's the Liquid Soap config file..
radio = mksafe(playlist("/var/www/html/mp3/playlist.m3u"))
# Define the output to the Icecast server
output.icecast(%vorbis,
  host = "localhost",
  port = 8000,
  password = "12345678",
  mount = "/stream",
  name = "My Stream",
  description = "Playing cool music",
  genre = "Various",
  radio
)

I tried adding fallback measures (live source and silenece.mp3) but that just stopped Liquid Soap from playing altogether.
